# how to draw the erd for this given reletional schema?

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

consider the following relational schema :

employee (person-name, street, city)

works (person-name, company-name, salary)

company (company-name, city)

manages (person-name, manager-name)

With primary keys : person-name , person-name , company-name and person-name respectively.

It seems 'employee' and 'company' have N:M relation with 'works' entity between them but the primary key of 'works' is just person-name not the combinition of person-name and company-name.

I can imagine  real world situations witch these relational schemas can be applied but still don't know the exact ER diagram for that.

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you got so far? Please read [asking] including about homework.

Comment: I know that with these relational schemas we will have a one-to-one relationship between 'employee' & 'works' and a one-to-many between 'works' and 'company' but these kind of relations i think are unnecessary and could be designed in better form.@philipxy

Comment: Pease read and address that link and edit your question to describe as much of the diagram as possible; comments are not for clarification. Most of an ER diagram looks like relational DDL. Re "'employee' and 'company' have N:M relation with 'works' entity between" Yes but in an ER diagram the lines with cardinalities at the ends are between the box for the relationship where an employee or company entity participates to the box for the participating entity or relationship. PS Please say what specific diagramming method you are to use.